# Can I install figlet from the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I really love [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org/), and use it frequently in my code and emails. It's really easy to install through the terminal in Linux, but I can't figure out how to install it on a Mac (OS X Yosemite 10.10.3). Does anyone know how to install FIGlet straight for Mac so I can run it from the terminal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can install it using [homebrew](http://brew.sh). Just type the following:

```
brew install figlet
```

If you don't have homebrew installed, you can simply do it by typing:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```